# How to add specific caption on my TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, book-class

i want to add "Halaman" as a caption that i blue circled above the list number on TOC as shown below:

[See this image](https://ibb.co/M7gxNqp)

Btw, "Halaman" means "Pages" in English. I want to put this word as a description above the list number of the TOC.

How to make this happens? Thanks.

Edit:

This is my main code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, openany]{book} 
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} \usepackage{fancyhdr} \usepackage{titlesec} \usepackage{setspace} \usepackage{tocloft} 
\fancyhf{} 
\cfoot{\thepage} 
\linespread{1.5} 
\pagestyle{plain} \renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}  
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\bfseries\centering} {\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{12pt}{} \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt} \renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI} \renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL} \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR} 
\begin{document} 
\clearpage 
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\frontmatter % 
\pagestyle{fancy} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} \include{cover1} 
\include{cover2} \linespread{1} \tableofcontents  
\listoffigures 
\listoftables 
\mainmatter % 
\end{document}
```

Btw, my cover 1, and cover 2 are not necessary since it hasn't been completely finished.

Comment: please upload your code as a  MWE

Comment: @jsbibra Hi, thanks for the answer. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\null\protect\hfill{Halaman}\protect\par}` before the first `\section`. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\null\protect\hfill{Halaman}\protect\par}
\section{a}
foo
\section{b}
bar
\section{c}
baz
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: @user516076 This would work almost the same in book-class. Just giv it a try! Good LuK!

Comment: Yes. It works but my problem is My TOC placed between acknowledgement and chapter. The order is like this: Cover, Acknowlegment, Foreword, TOC, Chapter1, Section, Chapter 2, and so on. So the "Halaman" becomes under my acknowlegment, and foreword. Please see my edit. Cover1 and cover2 contains the acknowlegement and somes page between cover and TOC.

Comment: Please see my result sir. Thanks. https://ibb.co/FJ390P3

Comment: I am happy to find you have tried. Why not placing the `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\null\protect\hfill{Halaman}\protect\par}` just after the `\begin{document}` then?

Comment: I'm more happy cz ure helping me sir. And it's work like what i want. when i put before `begin{document}` instead of "after". So, thank you so much.

Comment: I am happy to hear that!